# Determine the cardinal direction of a polyline

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, line, aspect

For a research project, I need to determine the cardinal direction of a polyline shoreline. For this, I would like to divide the coastline into 200 m sections, so that the cardinal direction is the same in the 200 m. My problem is that the tool "Aspect" (Spatial Analyst) only works with raster data and not with polylines.

Is there a way to determine the cardinal direction of a polyline?

Comment: In which classes? N-E-S-W? What if it is not possible for a 200 m section? For example the first 200 m of the shoreline looks lik `/|_/|_`

Comment: [Calculate Geometry Attribute](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm) tool computes line bearing?

Comment: Aspect is a 3D/elevation/slope property, which sounds different than what you are looking for.

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like it to be displayed in degrees from 0 to 360 °. It is true that the coastline is not always straight. I imagined it in such a way that the starting and end points of each 200m are connected and from which the cardinal direction is determined.

Comment: The "Tool Calculate Geometry Attributes looks" promising! I'll take a closer look! Thank you so much.